# How to make input fields (text) end where the divs end?

Tags: css

How to make input fields (text) end where the divs end? Now they go pass the grey box. See jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/FNZD6/

```
input[type="text"].normal100{
display:block;
font-size: 1.6em;
width:100%;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why this happens, but here is a fix.

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You'll need to prefix that too. I always set the `box-sizing` on everything but you can set it on specific elements if you wish.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FNZD6/2/)

Answer (score -1):

The `input` field is slightly bigger than the divs in your example because of the left and right borders. Easiest way to fix that is to explicitly set those to 0:

```
input[type="text"].normal100{
    display:block;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:0;
}
```

You'll probably want to add a border to your div.

Comment: I do not want to add borders to the div or remove borders from the input field.